# How to do a simple task simultaneously on android using java

Tags: java, android

I am writing inside an activity.

I simply want to set a variable of this activity to true, wait 5 seconds and switch the variable back to false without freezing the current thread execution.

Any help is appreciated. I have googled this for hours and tried all sorts to no success.

Comment: Have you tryed to run this as BackgroundTask? When switch to false kill the task.

Comment: I attempted this and it didn't work, I use a boolean and while loop to set if the task was done

Comment: there are many posts on the same topic, mention why those failed for you... you question might go flagged down if you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the **AsyncTask**.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Once created, a task is executed very simply:

```
 new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement the ASyncTask interface, and sleep inside the `doInBackground()` method and change your variable back in the `onPostExecute()` method

in your class you have you boolean variable

> boolean bValue = false;

Then add a private class inside your Activity

```
private class sleepFiveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     protected void onPreExecute() {
         bValue = true;
     }

     protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         try {

              Thread.sleep(5000); //sleep for 5 seconds 
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              // handle the exception...        
               // For example consider calling Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); here.
         }
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         bValue = false;
     }
 }
```

and when you want to execute it run

> new sleepFiveTask ().execute();

Answer (score 0):

You can do that starting a `Thread`. Example:

```
boolean myvar = true;

new Thread(
  new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
      SystemClock.sleep(5000);
      myvar = false;
    }
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: tried this, froze current thread execution

Comment: It makes no sense. If your execution is really freezing, must be for another reason as this start a paralell Thread that doesn't run in the main UI thread.

Comment: also you have an extra }, thanks again for your response though

Comment: I thought this too, as I usually program in java this was what I tried first, my program is massive so posting an example is too difficult, I shall try this small scale where it should work without fault and get back to you :) thanks again